# Hypersurfaces whose unit normal $N$ satisfies $[N,X] =0$ for every tangent vector field $X$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $M$ be a hypersurface of a Riemannian manifold, and assume that $M$ satisfies the following property:

> For each $p \in M$, given a unit normal vector field $N$ defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, the Lie bracket $[N,X]$ vanishes for all tangent vector fields on $U$.

Is the family of such hypersurfaces well-known?

Comment: Fermi’s coordinates? That is to say, using coordinates on M and the normal exponential along M you always get N such that its Lie bracket vanish against tangents X.